# Digital audio formatting

Tags: audio, arduino-uno, sampling, digital-analog-converter, hc-05

I have a vectorized wav file with values between -1 and 1, 88,200 samples, 44.1 kHz sampling rate to hear the audio within two seconds. I'd like to send the audio through bluetooth to a bluetooth module, arduino, DAC, and 3.5mm breakout board with earbuds.

I am getting crackly audio when I receive it at the end. I tried to recreate this is MATLAB and it turns out to be a combination of the scaling (multiplying + shifting the values over 0) and the sampling rate change due to the receivers. Of course, I could be completely recking the sampling frequency with inefficient Arduino code, but since a factor is also the initial scaling my guess is that I am misunderstanding something fundamental to audio processing.

**What is the proper way to format and or scale the values between 0-4095 (which are needed for the DAC input) so that the audio itself is not distorted upon listening *due to the scaling factor*, sampling rate retention aside?** OR is there something *else* I am missing in the big picture of this?

**Clarification**: Currently I am using the python sockets library to send an audio string array char by char into an Arduino array and reading them as an integers, then inputting into the DAC. Not sure if python sockets is the best way to go, there should be something better or a more robust implementation of sockets to send the data

**UPDATE:** I realized that the HC-05 uses [SPP bluetooth protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Serial_Port_Profile_(SPP)), which seems to be waaay too low resolution to send reliable audio.  I will see if I can send a more compressed audio file, store it in the arduino, then output to the DAC. That could provide more reliable audio.

Comment: The Bluetooth codec is going to handle all of this for you.  What codec are you using?  Why do you need to use 12-bit PCM audio?

Comment: I am using a WAV format, which I have realized is uncompressed and seems like an issue when sending that many samples to the bluetooth module from my PC over python.  And I dont need any format in particular, I just want to use whatever has the best chance of working in the end, that is, being able to send all the samples in a for loop from a PC  and listening through earbuds. I imagine it has to be 12 bit because the DAC only takes values between 0-4095.

Comment: Why not use the codecs built into the Bluetooth stack you're using, which can be adaptive?  You really don't want to send raw PCM over the limited bandwidth of Bluetooth.

Comment: I am using sockets in python (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)  and python "bluetooth" (really just a bluetooth socket object).  This socket library is very low level, so for me its been a hassle finding out even how to send the data.  I'm sure there's a better way to send it using this library though, just not sure how.  And yes, absolutely I should change from PCM to something else.  Do you have any suggestions for a python library with better built in "adaptive Bluetooth stack" / and or better documentation somewhere?

Comment: These codecs are generally built into the Bluetooth module.  Look at modules that implement A2DP, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting in and out values in your samples? I know that video that includes audio, that could be one thing being overlooked, anyhow, that can cause issues for uploading to YouTube. It seems similar to this, because it might not know where to begin and end and it can affect audio too.

Another issue may be the format of the samples, against Bluetooth technology. AAC should probably be the format, but confirm this because I am not 100% sure what all it will accept.

Comment: What do you mean setting in and out values?

Comment: Sorry, I do note now that Arduino is supposed to support wav format, but I don’t see a stop or out function.

Comment: In for when a track begins, out for when it ends.

Comment: I see it in the frequency function

Answer (score -1):

The library has an example for bandwidth:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AudioFrequencyMeter

But there are other functions for begin() and end().  You could declare them as variable to your start and end times within the samples, such that one will be the active track at a given time. You could also declare your frequency() as a constant value of 44.1, but you might have to escape the period for that. (It otherwise reads 60 to 1500.)